# Google ML Kit JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512) on rk3399 motherboard

Tags: android, google-mlkit

When I use Google ML Kit for pose detection.Running pose detection on rk3399 motherboard will cause such problems in about four minutes, but it can run for a long time on sdm660.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/344

Which version of pose-detection are you using?

17.0.1-beta7 has the fix for the issue linked above.